# jar file built with maven can't find configuration file

Tags: java, maven, jar

I built a jar file with maven. I am using the following code in the only class in the jar file to try to access the config file.

```
 InputStream is = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

The config.properties file is in the jar file located at Path /

I don't see any error messages. But when I try to access the values in the Properties object, the values are null.

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 prop.load(is);
 serverUrl=prop.getProperty("serverUrl");
```

serverUrl is null.

Any suggestions on how to get the values in the config file in the jar file?

Comment: you should add the error that you are getting

Comment: Try  `Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")` or put your config in same package as `MyClass`.

Comment: no error message that I can see, but when I try to access the values, there is a null value or a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue before I realized that the following way is only good for loading files in your classpath.

```
InputStream is = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

For picking files regardless of whether they are in classpath or not, I use [Apache FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). For e.g I used following and it worked like a charm.

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path_to_your_file), "UTF-8");
IOUtils.toInputStream(str, "UTF-8"); // if you need InputStream object
```

You can have a look at other APIs provided by [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) too other than `readFileToString`

Answer (score 0):

Typically in maven, you locate resources under src/main/resources.

Then you can access these resources by using the classloader:

```xml
try (InputStream in = Myclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties") {
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I updated my question and code to reflect the change. So my code appears to access the file but the values are null.

Comment: Or at least I should say InputStream is no longer null